# Cannot access Internet after connected to VPN

Tags: centos, vpn

I have set up a VPN on my CentOS server. Client side can connect to sever 
side, and ping to each other. However, I can not access internet any more.

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
      inet addr:192.168.9.1  P-t-P:192.168.9.11  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1496  Metric:1
      RX packets:748 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
      RX bytes:44177 (43.1 KiB)  TX bytes:84 (84.0 b)

seth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5D:A0:02:BB
      inet addr:118.193.160.45  Bcast:118.193.160.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
      inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fea0:2bb/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:467576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:165699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:94233225 (89.8 MiB)  TX bytes:45836762 (43.7 MiB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:54:43:1B
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

I enabled ipv4 forwarding ,also I can roll out that this is not a DNS issue.

Comment: What VPN service are you using?

Comment: Do you want your internet access to go over the VPN, or just resources that are on the other side of the VPN?

Comment: At the very least include `ifconfig` output from before the VPN is brought up and after the VPN is brought up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because your VPN client is routing all internet traffic through the tunnel, but your VPN gateway is not setup to allow that traffic (access policies).  If this is the case, you have two options:

1. Enable split tunneling on your VPN client so that only traffic destined for the VPN subnet will use the tunnel and all other traffic will use the internet.
2. Setup access rules on your VPN gateway to allow traffic through to the internet from VPN clients.

You may want to update your question to provide information about your VPN client and VPN server software.